# Mysql: Compare 2 types of JSON data ["a", "b", "c"] vs {“a”: true, “b”: true, "c":true}

Tags: mysql, index

I want to create a field like unordered_set (unique elements) in C++. In mysql, I use JSON field, there are 2 ways to do:

- tags = [“a”, “b”, “c”, …], application layer will ensure about uniqueness.
- tags = {“a”: true, “b”: true, “c”: true, …}

The number of elements of field tags is about 100. At this time, I don’t care about multi-valued indexes. I want to consider about these operations:

- Add a element into tags
- Find a element in tags

If tags is an array, searching is O(n). 
If tags is a map (object), does this field have better performance ?? 
I wonder that which internal data structure mysql uses to represent JSON field like {“a”: true, “b”: true}: hashtable, tree ???

Comment: *The number of elements is about 100.* This is the amount of elements per array/object, or this is amount of possible element values in array/object? If first - what is the amount of possible element values? for example - up to 100 from 250/10k/1kk/infinite...

Comment: @Akina: number of elements in field tags is about 100. The number of rows in table is about 10k.

Comment: *number of elements in field tags is about 100* i.e. the tags values vary as 'aa','ab',...,'cu','cv' (100 possible values), and only some of them (for example, only 50 from these 100) are present in any separate tags array?

Comment: @akina In my system, there are only 100 possible values of tag. Therefore, fields tags only has a maximum of 100 elements.

Comment: If so then think about SET datatype. 100 possible values needs in two SET columns (each column may store up to 64 bit flags). You may work with their data in both numeric and string representation, the data may be tested/searched by using both common bitwise operators and specific ones. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Comment: @akina My table is small, I think that JSON field is the simplest way. I only consider about how to store data {a: true, b: true, ...} or [a, b,..]

Comment: If you need in keys uniqueness then you must use an object. JSON implementation in MySQL does not support object properties duplicates in the JSON object. When there are those dups in the value to be saved then MySQL stores the most last value only. But you must define the column definitely as JSON datatype and not VARCHAR/TEXT datatype.

Comment: Additionally: if you want the table to be compact then (1) use short properties names (2) use short numeric properties values. I.e. the value should be like `'{"a":0, "b":0, ...}'`.

Comment: @akina Thank you for your reply. In conclusion, I think we have 3 options. (1): data normalization, use another table to save tags. (2) JSON field like hashmap. We can use index to find which rows contain a tag with (1), but (2) cannot. Option 3: use JSON array and create multi-valued index on arrray. The application layer takes care of uniqueness.

Comment: *The application layer takes care of uniqueness* Trigger may do this on the server side.